# refer to specific parameter by object in array?

Tags: python, parameters, expression, keyword, generalization

So I'm really not sure how to word this question, or I'm sure I could just google it.

I have a function such as:

```
def example(parameter1 = "", parameter2 = "", parameter3 =""):
    print(parameter1)
    print(parameter2)
    print(parameter3)
```

And I want to be able to, say, call it 3 times and pass in only one parameter at once such as:

```
example(parameter1 = "Hello")
example(parameter2 = "Stack")
example(parameter3 = "Overflow")
```

But in my real code I need to generalize this heavily and have a LOT more parameters, so I want to be able to do something along the lines of:

```
paramnames = ['parameter1', 'parameter2', 'parameter3']
parameters = ['Hello', 'Stack', 'Overflow']

for i in range(3):
    example(paramnames[i] = parameters[i])
```

Is there any way in python to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [argument packing](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), and uses `*` or `**` to denote positional and named arguments:

```
paramnames = ['parameter1', 'parameter2', 'parameter3']
parameters = ['Hello', 'Stack', 'Overflow']

for name, value in zip(paramnames, parameters):
    example(**{name: value})

def example(parameter1="", parameter2="", parameter3=""):
    print(parameter1)
    print(parameter2)
    print(parameter3)
```

Keep in mind that if an argument isn't passed, it'll be the default. So the output is:

```
Hello



Stack



Overflow
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `dict` and the `**` notation:

```
parameters = {'parameter1': 'Hello',
              'parameter2': 'Stack', 
              'parameter3': 'Overflow'}

for k, v in parameters.items():
    example(**{k: v})
```

If you need to retain order, use an `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 0):

why not using a dict like that :

```
paramnames = ['parameter1', 'parameter2', 'parameter3']
parameters = ['Hello', 'Stack', 'Overflow']

for i in range(3):
    example({paramnames[i] : parameters[i]})
```

and :

```
def example(para_dict):
    for k,v in para_dict.items():
        print(v)
```

if you want to use every parameter on deffrent code you can testing on "k"

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this.

The most straight forward way is probably to use a dictionary to hold the arguments before you pass them all to the function using `example(**param_dict)`.

A more "fancy" approach would be to use `functools.partial` to a callable object with some parameters prespecified. You'd do something like `example = partial(example, parameter1="hello")` to add parameters, then just call `example()` at the end. This approach could be useful if the parameters come from many different places and you need to keep the function with its parameters around for a while, like in a callback.